# HTML5 + Bootstrap + IE11 + Windows7にて、フォーカスを当てた時の挙動がおかしい

Tags: html, css, jquery, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

HTML5、Bootstrapにてページを作成しています。 
IE11でテキストフィールドにフォーカスを当てた際に、謎の事象が発生しました。 
１．枠線の影が消える 
２．テキストフィールドの左上にグレーの影が表示される

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
この現象は下記の環境で発生しています。 
・Windows7 Professional SP1（32bit） 
・IE 11.0.9600.18537 (更新バージョン 11.0.38(KB3203621) 
・画面解像度 横：1280px 
・DPIなし（詳細は質問の最後に記載） 
Windows10のIE11やEdge、Chrome等では発生しておらず、 1280px以外の解像度では発生していません。

上記現象が再現できる状態のものを以下のサイトにアップロードしています。

http://servertest.html.xdomain.jp/
現象自体はテーブルやテキストフィールドの横幅を変えれば発生しなくなるのは分かっています。しかし、テーブルの作り方によっては画面解像度横1280px以外でも発生するのではないかと危惧しています。

私も周りのPCでは上記環境で全て再現していますが、再現しないPCもあるようです。
※自分の目で見ていないので確証は定かではありません。
IEの不具合ではないかと疑っているのですが、同じようなことが発生する文献がある等、何か知恵や情報をいただけないかと思っています。

==============
※※※※※※DPIなしの確認方法について※※※※※※ 
①デスクトップを右クリックし「画面の解像度」を選択 
②「テキストやその他項目の大きさの変更」を選択 
③ラジオボタンが・「小（100%)」になっているか

Comment: 問題の環境でインターネットオプションで[GPU レンダリングでなく、ソフトウェア レンダリングを使用する](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2528233/how-to-enable-or-disable-software-rendering-in-internet-explorer)を選択した場合に改善しますか？

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/65735